# OmniScript LWC embedded in FlexCard

Tags: lightning-web-components, vlocity, omnistudio

I have an Omniscript (named "filesFileUploadEnglish") that I have embedded inside of a FlexCard (named documentManager) using the "Custom LWC" element in the FlexCard.

I have set two attributes on the Custom LWC element in the FlexCard:

- linked (Id)
- folder (Id)

[image]

How can I access these values on the child OmniScript LWC?
I have tried using the standard OmniScript merge format but to no avail (see below).
The variable values are blank when previewing the parent FlexCard and when embedding the parent on a record page.

Is there a way to access the "parent" data in this situation, similar to the 'parent-attribute' available for child FlexCards??

[image]